# Comparing Negative values in bash using arrays

Tags: bash

I do have a interesting problem that I am trying to tackle but I am
yet unable to do so.

Let suppose that I have 2 arrays.

Array One:

```
1 -2 3 -2 2 -4
```

Array Two:

```
-2 -3 4 5 2 -5
```

I want to be able to actually compare the i-th value of both `Array one` and `Array two`:

- If both are negative then I would input in `Array Three` `0`
- If they are both positive I will add a `1`
- If they are opposites I need to insert a `2`

Output:

```
2 0 1 2 1 0
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: What if an element is zero?

Comment: Hello, a element can never be 0 since the two arrays are actually stock values so if both are up together then there is a relation down as well so the value can never be 0 am very new to bash

Comment: Really, don't use bash for this. Use Python or Perl, not bash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're familiar with C, C++ or Java, then you'll find this variant of `bash`'s `for`-loop quite familiar too.  `bash` does arithmetic evaluation with `(( ... ))` so we'll use that when comparing values:

```
array1=(  1 -2  3 -2  2 -4 )
array2=( -2 -3  4  5  2 -5 )

array3=( )

for (( i=0; i < ${#array1[@]}; ++i )); do
    if (( array1[i] < 0 && array2[i] < 0 )); then
        array3[$i]=0
    elif (( array1[i] > 0 && array2[i] > 0 )); then
        array3[$i]=1
    else
        array3[$i]=2
    fi
done

echo "${array3[@]}"
```

This also works well with the `ksh93` shell, from which `bash` got many of its features.

Answer (score 3):

A straight way:

```
arr1=(1 -2 3 -2 2 -4)
arr2=(-2 -3 4 5 2 -5)

i=0

while [[ "$i" -lt "${#arr1[@]}" ]]; do
  a=$(( ${arr1[$i]} * ${arr2[$i]} ))
  if [[ "$a" -lt 0 ]]; then
    echo 2
  else
    if [[ "${arr1[$i]}" -gt 0 ]]; then
      echo 1
    else
      echo 0
    fi
  fi
  : "$((i = i + 1))"
done | paste -sd ' ' -
```

Comment: Slightly obfuscated in a backhand trick shot kind of way, but +1 for creative use of `paste` and `:`.